# Android API for analyzing PCM data?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, pcm

Is there an Android-native API which would help me analyzing raw PCM data?

(Just basic things: frequency, volume of a data piece.)

If not, are there good (non-Android-specific) references to reading PCM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in reading up on the AudioTrack class.

From the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

An article: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/580/android-audio-play-a-wav-file-on-an-audiotrack/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `musicg` library.. It is based on `Java`